# using the confirm method when leaving site

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, confirm

I want a confirm message to popup when clicking on an external link. Though it doesnt want to work out. I dont get the confirm popup when i click on an external link. Any solutions ?

Javascript code

```
function warning(){
    var warning = confirm('Do you want to leave');
    if(!warning){
    alert("Staying on site");
    return false;
    } else {
        alert("Leaving site");
    return true;
    }
}

function init() {
    var warn = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for(i=0; i<warn.length; i++)
        if(warn[i].className == "meny"){
            var link = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }
    for(i=0; i<link.length; i++){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        if(links[i].className == "external"){
            links.onclick = warning;
        }
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
<ul class="meny"">
<li><a class="external" href="https://www.mah.se">Mah</a></li>
<li><a class="external" href="https://www.google.se/">Google</a></li>
<li><a class="external" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></li>
<li><a class="external" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Digitalt</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Kultur</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Nöje</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Familj</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resor</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inrikes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Utrikes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Jobb</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: generally, you'll need to delete the href and replace it with '#', then use js to manually send them there. That's really the only reliable way to get the popup to happen before the href. For editor windows and things you can also make it fire on body onclose. These are not good practices for non-internal webpages, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can only be accomplished by handling the `onbeforeunload` event. Your handler should return a string, which is the message that appears to the user. A simple example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'are you sure you want to leave?';  
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rHkfM/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to slightly modify your code:

```
function init() {
    var warn = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for(i=0; i<warn.length; i++)
        if(warn[i].className == "meny"){
            var link = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    }
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i=0; i<link.length; i++){
        if(links[i].className == "external"){
            links.external = true;
        }
    }
}
```

then add:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    if (event.srcElement.external)
        return 'are you sure you want to leave?';  
};
```

Please pay attention, this line:

```
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

must be outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, in this way you can choose when show or not show the popup message. Basically you can flag with a private attribute your anchors and then check if they are external link. When the check is positive show the confirm through the onbeforeunload.

Comment: I will do so, it seems to be working. Almost finished. Thank you !

Comment: thanks, if so, may I ask you to pick my answer as more correct?

Comment: And then... Have you found helpful the answer?